# How can I reach component variables in custom validator?

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I want to make custom validator which would make submit button available only if text in form is unique.
I have VulnarabilitiesClass instance, which contains an array of objects with id and name fields.
After typing any text in my form I get this error:
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.systemVulnarabilities')

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
  <label>
    Vulnarability Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="name" required>
  </label>
</form>

<p>
  Form Status: {{ profileForm.status }}
</p>
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid">Submit</button>
```

```
this.systemVulnarabilities = new VulnarabilitiesClass();

profileForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required,this.UniqueNameValidator],
  });

private UniqueNameValidator(control: FormControl): ValidationErrors{
  let vulnarabilityName: string = control.value;
  console.log(vulnarabilityName);
  console.log(this.systemVulnarabilities.displayList.toString());//no output already
  let found: number = this.systemVulnarabilities.displayList.map(function(e) { return e.name; }).indexOf(vulnarabilityName); //mistake
  if(found === -1){
    return {invalidPassword: 'this name already exists'};
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your VulnarabilitiesClass code?

Comment: maybe show more of the component class code. If "this.systemVulnarabilities is undefined" it certainly is not properly instantiated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error happens because `UniqueNameValidator` method is executed with different from component context `this`. The reason for this is that in javascript context `this` depends on how the function is executed and not where it was declared.

The simple fix is to use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method that makes sure correct context `this`

```
this.UniqueNameValidator.bind(this)
```

Also, if your validator is synchronous then you need to wrap your validators in array otherwise Angular will treat it as asynchronous validator:

```
name: ['', [Validators.required, this.UniqueNameValidator.bind(this)]],
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you could use a closure and make your Validator contextual with the variable `systemVulnarabilities`, like this:

```
profileForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required,this.UniqueNameValidator(systemVulnarabilities)],
  });
```

```
UniqueNameValidator(systemVulnarabilities): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: FormControl)=>{
    let vulnarabilityName: string = control.value;
  let found: number = systemVulnarabilities.displayList.map(function(e) { return e.name; }).indexOf(vulnarabilityName); //mistake
  if(found === -1){
    return {invalidPassword: 'this name already exists'};
  }
  return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the other "clasic" way is define the function like

```
private UniqueNameValidator(){
  return (control: FormControl)=>{
         ....
  }
}
```

and add the validator -see the () at the end of UniqueNameValidator

```
profileForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required,this.UniqueNameValidator()],
  });
```